# Apache2 VirtualHost going to default directory

Tags: 14.04, apache2, virtualhost

I have a default virtual host conf file for apache2, and have copied it to `mysite.com.conf` and changed the `NameServer` and `Directory`.

But when I go to `mysite.com` it stills shows the default directory content?

Any ideas how to debug this? Im at Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you disable default site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding it into `/etc/hosts` like `127.0.1.2 mysite.com`.